# Fixed button that stays even when viewPager is swiped

Tags: android, button, android-viewpager, swipe

I have have a close button [x] in two of my xml (with floating dialog theme), which i am using viewPager with.

The close button is located at the top right hand corner of the two xml. However, as i swipe left or right, the button gets swipe to and fro too which looks really weird. Any idea to make the button stay fixed even when i swipe the pages?

Code from one of the page (both pages are similar):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="350dp" 
    android:minHeight="700dp"
    android:background="#CECECE"
    android:id="@+id/dialogLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblInfo"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
    android:text="Information"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="40dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnClose"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="320dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
    android:background="#0000"
    android:src="@drawable/close" />

</TableRow>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblInfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="17dp" />



</LinearLayout>
```

The viewPager xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="612dp"
    android:layout_height="700dp">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post the xml from your layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end what I did was to place the close button  (btnClose) and page title (lblTitle) outside the viewPager as advised from @Luksprog . The close button is fixed when i applied onPageChangeListener for the page title so that the TextView would change the title accordingly to the page flipped! Codes :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewpagerbase);

    //add onClickListener for the btnClose
    ImageButton btnClose = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
    btnClose.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });


    //attach the viewPage adapter 
    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    //set listener for page change 
    myPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

}   //end of onCreate
```