# Make button stay fixed when swiping a viewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe

Basically, I want a button that appears on a certain page on my viewPager to stay on position on swipe (for design purposes). I have read the closely similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281765/fixed-button-that-stays-even-when-viewpager-is-swiped) but I didn't understand how the OP implemented it. My button and viewPager are defined separately on my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>


     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button_register"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_above="@+id/indicator"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginBottom="96dp"
         android:text="Register" 
         android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I detect page swipes with *OnPageChangeListener*. Here is a graphic example of what I want to implement:

[image: example]

Thank you!

**EDIT**

Here is the file *imageview.xml*, which is defined for each page in the viewPager. I included the button here as advised by @attels (it was previously defined in the main activity layout), but now my app crashes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivImageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:contentDescription="@string/welcome1"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

<include layout="@layout/imageview_page"/>

<Button
     android:id="@+id/button_register"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_above="@+id/indicator"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginBottom="96dp"
     android:text="Register" 
     android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**FINAL EDIT**
So in order for any Button or Text or whatever that you want to keep fixed in a viewPager's page, you need to define said element in the page's layout (NOT in the main activity's layout) and also instantiate the button inside the fragment. Thanks!

Comment: in the post you referred controls are placed outside viewpager. i have never checked but for trying purpose you can try taking a framelayout and inside it take viewpager as child and a button which is placed anywhere in screen as per your requirement as child of framelayout. currently it seems your button is part of the fragment layout you are using in your framgnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

This method in FragmentPagerAdapter shows each screen.

```
 @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position); 
        }
```

So that means that you need to add the button in ArrayListFragments layout here:

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container, false); 
            // Here is the layout that the fragment is going to show.
            //some code
            return v;
        }
```

And here is the fragment_pager_list layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="146dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So now the button is going to follow the screen.

Comment: Thanks, I used this to set up my viewPager, but I included my button in the same layout as the viewpager (as Rajen Raiyarela  pointed out). I tried putting my button in fragment_pager_list layout as advised (where I have a ImageView also defined, as my viewpager consists of images), but at the time of running, the app crashes. [Here](http://pastebin.com/dvdLnLBC) are the methods in my implementation, and I also posted the other layout in the original post. What could be failing?

Comment: Can you add the logcat error stacktrace here? But FragmentImageView.newInstance(itemData.get(position)) should be the way how to pass object to Fragment, and add this object through Bundle as serializable or parcable. There is a similar pattern in documentation that i added in the answer, but it shouldn't cause error in your case.

Comment: [Here it is](http://pastebin.com/yUer4aEn). It seems I'm wrongly addressing the button in my main activity's onCreate (I'm doing it like btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_register);, but im not sure if it won't look on the button as it is on the other layout now)

Comment: You should define the button in the Fragment, the same way how you are doing it with: ivImage = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.ivImageView);
(Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button1);